# Bitmap ByteCount remaining the same after compression

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, image-compression

I'm trying to see the results of various compression qualities with something like this:

```
private static Bitmap codec(Bitmap src, Bitmap.CompressFormat format,
                                int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        src.compress(format, quality, os);

        byte[] array = os.toByteArray();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
    }
```

I have a Bitmap called `bitmap`, and I'm comparing it to compressed version:

```
Bitmap compressed = codec(bitmap,Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG ,10);
Log.d("result","bitmap=" + bitmap.getByteCount() + " compressed=" + compressed.getByteCount());
```

No matter what photo I select to load into `bitmap`, the compressed version's byte count remains the same as bitmap's bytecount -- though, if I load `compressed` into an `ImageView`, the quality is very noticeably lower.

Is the size really staying the same while lowering the visual quality of the image? Am I getting the size of the file incorrectly?

EDIT:
Even stranger, the result size is showing `16343040` bytes for an image that says `1.04mb` in gallery details.

I'm getting the original `bitmap` through `onActivityResult` using:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
```

Where `selectedImageUri` is either from `getData()` or the file selected from the device's storage.

Comment: There is no compressed version of the Bitmap. As soon as you decode the array or the stream you uncompress/decompress the data. As the bitmap has the same resolution as the original it needs the same amount of bytes in memory. 'the result size is showing 16343040 bytes for an image that says 1.04mb in gallery details.'. You could have been as friendly to write that as 16.343.040 No not strange. A jpg needs less bytes then a bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Android Developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount()) for `Bitmap`, `getByteCount()` returns the minimum number of bytes that can be used to represent the pixels in the image, i.e. the maximally compressed size, even for the uncompressed image! You should use `getAllocationByteCount()` instead, as it returns the number of bytes the `Bitmap` is actually taking using.

Comment: Seems I'm getting the same results even after switching to `getAllocationByeCount()`.

Comment: In your `codec` method, can you try seeing if `src.compress()` returns true?

Comment: Also, try using the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` method to directly decode `os`, instead of converting it to a `byte[]` in-between

Comment: Sorry, meant to mention that I already made sure `compress()` was returning true -- but it's also very visibly clear that the image is being compressed!

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap is a memory data structure to display images. Your `byte[] array` will tell the size as on disk: `array.length`.

*(To be entirely clear.)* A Bitmap in memory will probably not use more or less memory. (Just when using another color model, like 256 indexed colors.)

Answer (score 1):

*BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray* converts a compressed image, into an uncompressed one (RGBA8 format). So, basically, your *codec()* function is taking in an RGBA8 image, compressing it, then decompressing it back to RGBA8 before returning the result.

This is talked about in [Smaller PNG Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TUvmlGoDrw&index=27&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE); Android doesn't use the compressed images *directly*; All image data has to be converted from compressed formats, to RGBA8 formats so that the rendering system can use them properly (see [Rendering Performance 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXQhu6qfTVU&index=33&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)).

If you want a smaller in-memory representation of your image, you need to use a different pixel format like RGB656 (which is discussed in [Smaller Pixel Formats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WqcEHXRWpM&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=26))